# Big O-Notation on my permutation function coded scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, big-o

Below code is implementation of permuting elements in list, coded by scala

```
def permute(list:List[Int]):List[List[Int]] =
  if(list.isEmpty) {
    Nil
  } else {
    var result: List[List[Int]] = Nil

    def recursion(plist: List[Int], rlist: List[Int]): Unit = {
      if (rlist.isEmpty)
        result ++= plist :: Nil

      if (plist != list.reverse)
        for (i <- rlist.indices) {
          val x = rlist(i)
          val xDropped = drop(x, rlist)
          val newPList = plist ++ (x :: Nil)
          recursion(plist ++ (x :: Nil), xDropped)
        }
    }

    recursion(Nil, list)
    result
  }

def drop(x:Int, list:List[Int]) = list.filter(_ != x)
val result = permute(xs)
result.foreach(println)
println(result.length)
```

and console will show as below.

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeL7T.png)
My concern is what is big-o notation on this function,
and how to calculate it?

I'd hope you to show detail description of the method that results big-o notation

Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your algorithm is far too complicated because of a lot of suboptimal steps. The Scala API is overwhelming if you first look at it and come from a imperative language, so this is understandable, but it makes your algorithm hard to analyse.

What is clear from the problem, is, that your algorithm has to be exponential because it enumerates exponentially many permutations.

The dominating factor for your complexity is the recursive call that you do for each element in your input for a list one element smaller. So your recursion depth is the number of elements in your input and the number of recursive calls in each step is as well that number. What we get as complexity is therefore O(n^n) = O(2^(n*ld(n)))

Now this would be your complexity if you returned your results in an optimal way, but you are using `result ++= plist :: Nil`. First, this is not functional style, which, without good reason, should be avoided. But if you do it, you should use a mutable Structure (e.g. ListBuffer) or at least prepend to a list. Here, you append to a list which is linear in its length. So the whole thing is quadratic in the number of elements you append to the list which is exponential. So what you get as complexity is in fact

O((2^(n*ld(n)))^2) = O(2^(2*n*ld(n)))

And constants in an exponent do make a difference even in O-notation.

Replacing `result ++= plist :: Nil` by `result = plist :: result` gives your algorithm optimal asymptotic complexity and makes it considerably faster.

There are however a few other issues with your algorithm that do not influence the asymptotic complexity:

- There is no need to iterate over the indices with `i <- rlist.indices`, you can directly iterate over the elements `x <- rlist`. This is also much faster as index-base access to a List takes linear time.
- Your method drop filters the list to remove one element. This can be achieved much simpler and faster if you use a set instead of a list where you can directly and efficiently remove elements.
- You append to your plist by appending a list: `plist ++ (x :: Nil)` but you could just prepend to the list, which is less convoluted and faster: `x :: plist`. Also, there is a :+ operator that appends just one element. You do not have to put an element into a list just to append it.

Here is a cleaned-up version of your code:

```
def permute(list:List[Int]):List[List[Int]] =
  if(list.isEmpty) {
    Nil
  } else {
    var result: List[List[Int]] = Nil

    def recursion(plist: List[Int], rlist: List[Int]): Unit = {
      if (rlist.isEmpty)
        result = plist :: result

      if (plist != list.reverse)
        for (x <- rlist) {
          val xDropped = drop(x, rlist)
          val newPList = x :: plist
          recursion(newPList, xDropped)
        }
    }

    recursion(Nil, list)
    result
  }
```

This is now quite fast.

Without thinking about performance I would have done it like this:

```
def perm[T](elements: Set[T]): List[List[T]] =
  if(elements.isEmpty)
    List(Nil)
  else
    for {
      element <- elements.toList
      rest <- perm(elements - element)
    } yield
      element :: rest
```

This is much cleaner and simpler and almost as fast as the optimized version of your code. Actually, I was surprised that your cleaned-up version is faster, but there are two reasons: firstly, we have to iterate over all elements over the set anyway, so being able to remove a single element is not much of an advantage, and then iteration over a list is faster than over a set. Secondly, my algorithm iterates over the result set and transforms its elements, that seems to be somewhat slower than building up the complete results.

This version finally is as fast or a little bit faster than your cleaned-up version:

```
def perm[T](elements: List[T], result: List[T]): List[List[T]] =
  if(elements.isEmpty)
    List(result)
  else
    for {
      element <- elements
      res <- perm(elements.filter(_!=element), element :: result)
    } yield res
def perm[T](elements: List[T]): List[List[T]] = perm(elements, Nil)
```

Probably there is an even faster, imperative way to do it, but this should be "good enough". The version in the standard library of Scala seems to be a lot slower than this.

And then there is of course an even faster and shorter functional version using an insert operation on lists:

```
def insert[T](elem: T, list: List[T]) =
  (0 to list.size).map{
     pos => list.take(pos) ++ (elem :: list.drop(pos))
  }
```

So now we can simply do this:

```
def perm[T](elements: List[T]) =
  elements.foldLeft(List(List[T]())){
    (results, element) => results.flatMap{insert(element,_)}
  }
```

So following the direct approach "permute n elements by permuting n-1 and inserting the next element at every position" turns out to be the shortest and fastest...